# Merge Spark output CSV files with a single header

Tags: scala, csv, hadoop, apache-spark

I want to create a data processing pipeline in AWS to eventually use the processed data for Machine Learning.

I have a Scala script that takes raw data from S3, processes it and writes it to HDFS or even S3 with **Spark-CSV**. I think I can use multiple files as input if I want to use **AWS Machine Learning** tool for training a prediction model. But if I want to use something else, I presume it is best if I receive a single CSV output file.

Currently, as I do not want to use **repartition(1)** nor **coalesce(1)** for performance purposes, I have used **hadoop fs -getmerge** for manual testing, but as it just merges the contents of the job output files, I am running into a small problem. I need **a single row of headers** in the data file for training the prediction model.

If I use `.option("header","true")` for the spark-csv, then it writes the headers to every output file and after merging I have as many lines of headers in the data as there were output files. But if the header option is false, then it does not add any headers.

Now I found an option to merge the files inside the Scala script with Hadoop API [`FileUtil.copyMerge`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String)). I tried this in `spark-shell` with the code below.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
val configuration = new Configuration();
val fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, new Path("smallheaders"), fs, new Path("/home/hadoop/smallheaders2"), false, configuration, "")
```

But this solution still just concatenates the files on top of each other and does not handle headers. **How can I get an output file with only one row of headers?**

I even tried adding `df.columns.mkString(",")` as the last argument for `copyMerge`, but this added the headers still multiple times, not once.

Comment: i m also facing the same issue .is this fixed ?

Comment: @senthilkumarp Unfortunately not. The only way I got the necessary result was using `df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(resultPath)` but that probably wouldn't work so well with larger data.

Comment: yes i too used the same coalesce(1)

Comment: how about filtering the DataFrame to zero rows, export that with header=true, export the rest of the data with header=false and than merge header with partitions?

Comment: @Boern this may work. Although I think it would require copying the headers file to the same output as the data and making sure it is always the first file. I think this current solution wouldn't allow to write into the same path. Of course appending might solve that problem, need to try and play around with it a while.

Comment: If you find an ellegant solution please let me know! I often had the same problem and I'd certainly upvote.

Comment: I am currently busy with another project, but if I come back to it, then I will keep this question in mind.

Comment: If the files are not that big i use the shell to remove, and re-add one, header lines:
head -1 getmerge.csv > header ;
grep -v "header1,header2," getmerge.csv > tmpcsv # or anything that only apperas in the headers ;
cat header tmpcsv > my.csv ;
rm getmerge.csv # clean up

Comment: @Boern + all: Does my answer not solve the problem?

Comment: @belka, It looks like your first solution is what V. Samma currently has, but it puts the header in the file multiple times. Your other solutions use `coalesce` and `repartition` which isn't ideal either. A nice solution would still have the data written by different workers, but produce a single file with 1 header

Comment: @KyleHeuton how could you write the data by several workers but having one file as output? You have to go through fetching all data to the driver...

I question the fact that my solution writes the header multiple times.

Comment: @bleka The "how" of that is the point of this question. One could imagine a flag to spark that tells it to only save a header with the file designated `part-0000`, or perhaps an intelligent concatenation that combines the files saved by multiple workers but only keeps the header from one of them. `copyMerge` looks like it just combines files, so if the files have headers the header will appear multiple times, or if the files lack headers there will be no header at all, as V. Samma says in the question. Or does `copyMerge` have different behavior in your answer?

Comment: @belka Unfortunately it's almost 2 years already since I posted this and I am not working with Spark anymore, but I remember the problem exactly as @Kyle Heuton described it. The problem was that if the output was giving multiple files, then you could either add header to all of them or none of them. And then by merging these, you would have multiple headers scattered in the data or none at all. Although I think `coalesce` fixed it, I think I remember it being slower than merging so ideally there could be a way of writing only headers to 1 file and when merging, use this as the first file.

Comment: @KyleHeuton There is actually no way to make sure the columns order in the first `part-000` file (the one with the specified header) is the same as in the second (or third...) file `part-000`. Because Spark doesn't know how to `union` different DataFrames with different column names.

Comment: @belka these aren't different dataframes with different columns though, these are just different partitions of the same dataframe with the same columns

Answer (score 7):

you can walk around like this.

- 1.Create a new DataFrame(headerDF) containing header names.
- 2.Union it with the DataFrame(dataDF) containing the data.
- 3.Output the union-ed DataFrame to disk with **option("header", "false")**.
- 4.merge partition files(part-0000**0.csv) using hadoop FileUtil

In this ways, all partitions have no header except for a single partition's content has a row of header names from the headerDF. When all partitions are merged together, there is a single header in the top of the file. Sample code are the following

```
  //dataFrame is the data to save on disk
  //cast types of all columns to String
  val dataDF = dataFrame.select(dataFrame.columns.map(c => dataFrame.col(c).cast("string")): _*)

  //create a new data frame containing only header names
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  val headerDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(List(Row.fromSeq(dataDF.columns.toSeq)).asJava, dataDF.schema)

  //merge header names with data
  headerDF.union(dataDF).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", "false").csv(outputFolder)

  //use hadoop FileUtil to merge all partition csv files into a single file
  val fs = FileSystem.get(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, new Path(outputFolder), fs, new Path("/folder/target.csv"), true, spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration, null)
```

Comment: How will this ensure that the header is at the top? Also, FileUtil.copyMerge is deprecated and hdfs getmerge is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Output the header using dataframe.schema
   ( val header = dataDF.schema.fieldNames.reduce(_ + "," + _))
2. create a file with the header on dsefs
3. append all the partition files (headerless) to the file in #2 using hadoop Filesystem API

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue, following the below approach to get single output file-

1. Write dataframe to hdfs with headers and without using `coalesce` or `repartition` (after the transformations).

```
dataframe.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save(hdfs_path_for_multiple_files)
```

2. Read the files from the previous step and write back to different location on hdfs with `coalesce(1)`.

```
dataframe = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv(hdfs_path_for_multiple_files)

dataframe.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').option('header', 'true').save(hdfs_path_for_single_file)
```

This way, you will avoid performance issues related to coalesce or repartition while execution of transformations (Step 1).
And the second step provides single output file with one header line.

Comment: Hi @Arati Nagmal, I don't work with Spark currently anymore so it's difficult for me to test it out. I would actually be curious about those transformations and would like to see some testing results, maybe how much time it takes to coalesce with the first and second approach and compare. Because for me, writing, reading and writing the same data again seems to be double the work for the same result. Of course the first write would take more time than the second, if you have applied some transformations to the dataframe, but is it quicker to write it twice instead of coalesce on the first try?

Comment: Hi @V.Samma, yes, this approach is very performance efficient in our case. The problem with using coalesce(1) along with transformations, is it executes transformations with parallelism 1. And takes lot of time to complete. That's why I divided into two steps.
And the second step takes around 2 minutes in our case, i.e. for data of around 3GB in CSV format.
I hope it clarifies your questions!

Answer (score 0):

To merge files in a folder into one file:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit =  {
  val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
  FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, hadoopConfig, null)
}
```

If you want to merge all files into one file, but still in the same folder (**but** this brings all data to the driver node):

```
dataFrame
      .coalesce(1)
      .write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(out)
```

Another solution would be to use solution #2 then move the one file inside the folder to another path (with the name of our CSV file).

```
def df2csv(df: DataFrame, fileName: String, sep: String = ",", header: Boolean = false): Unit = {
    val tmpDir = "tmpDir"

    df.repartition(1)
      .write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", header.toString)
      .option("delimiter", sep)
      .save(tmpDir)

    val dir = new File(tmpDir)
    val tmpCsvFile = tmpDir + File.separatorChar + "part-00000"
    (new File(tmpCsvFile)).renameTo(new File(fileName))

    dir.listFiles.foreach( f => f.delete )
    dir.delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the schema of the header and read all file from the folder using the option drop malformed of spark-csv. This should let you read all the files in the folder keeping only the headers (because you drop the malformed).
Example:

```
val headerSchema = List(
  StructField("example1", StringType, true),
  StructField("example2", StringType, true),
  StructField("example3", StringType, true)
)

val header_DF =sqlCtx.read
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")
  .option("inferSchema","false")
  .schema(StructType(headerSchema))
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .load("folder containg the files")
```

In header_DF you will have only the rows of the headers, from this you can trasform the dataframe the way you need.

Comment: Although I don't work with Spark anymore, I don't have a system where I can test this, your example might work very well with smaller structs. But I had a case where we had 200-300 fields in one struct (structs nested in other structs etc) and this schema was changing quite quickly as the system changed. So defining a schema manually wasn't an option.

Answer (score -4):

```
 // Convert JavaRDD  to CSV and save as text file
        outputDataframe.write()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                // Header => true, will enable to have header in each file
                .option("header", "true")
```

Please follow the link with Integration test on how to write a single header

> http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/write-a-csv-text-file-from-spark/