# How can I export a very big PySpark dataframe as a CSV file?

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark

My question might be similar to some other questions on stackoverflow but it is quiet different.

I have a very large PysPark dataframe (about 40 million rows and 30 columns) . I am going to export the file as a `CSV` file. I tried different ways but got errors for all of them.

So far, I have tried:

```
df.repartition(1).write.save(path='the path and name of the file.csv', format='csv', mode='overwrite', header='true')
```

and

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('path and the name of the file.csv', index=False)
```

It runs about 1 hour and then I get the following errors for both of them:

```
y4JJavaError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-040553681ce4> in <module>
.
.
.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o666.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to do this task for large dataframes which be fast too.

I am using  `python3.7.1`, `pyspark2.4`, and `jupyter4.4.0`

Comment: I would use the Pyspark df but without the repartition. You are probably running out of memory.
If you really need a single file at the end you could loop through them and stitch them together using Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Spark output CSV files with a single header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056152/merge-spark-output-csv-files-with-a-single-header)

Comment: @simon_dmorias could you please explain more with exact codes or some link?

Comment: I also wrote the code without repartition and still the same problem