# Marge Move/Copy Large data file in dbutils using a Notebook in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, databricks, dbutils

Writing the dataframe as a tsv in **databricks** file system (DBFS) with huge data size (30GB to 1TB). I am currently using the below code

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\t").option("nullValue",None).option("header", inheader).mode("overwrite").save(tsvPathtemp)
```

For 100GB it taking an hour to copy the file.
I had tried removing the coalesce(1) it copied multiple files but I want one tsv file as a output.

Can any one suggest the best approaches/code to copy the files.

Also how can I import hadoop file system in databricks notebook. refer below question

```py
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
```

**[Merge Spark output CSV files with a single header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056152/merge-spark-output-csv-files-with-a-single-header)**

Comment: Try using the hdfs module of python? https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Can't use it, as file system I am using is DBFS.